# Better way to write named scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

This named scope is working fine.

```
named_scope :search, lambda {|search_txt|
      {
        :conditions => ["field1 like ? or field2 like ? or field3 like ?","#{search_txt}%","#{search_txt}%","#{search_txt}%"]
      }
  }
```

Instead of writing search_txt three time in conditions. Can I handle the same scenario with passing search_txt only once in conditions ?

Something like

```
named_scope :search, lambda {|search_txt|
      {
        :conditions => ["field1 like ? or field2 like ? or field3 like ?","#{search_txt}%"]
      }
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this works in a scope, but there is another way to write conditions:

```
MyModel.all(:conditions=>['field_1 LIKE :q OR field_2 LIKE :q OR field_3 LIKE :q', {:q=> 'search_txt'}])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
named_scope :search, lambda {|search_txt|
  {
    :conditions => ["field1 like :q or field2 like :q or field3 like :q",{:q => "#{search_txt}%"}]
  }
```

}